Is it possible to export an Azure Custom Vision model for lower running costs?
A customer has a webapp that is reliant on an Azure Custom Vision (ACV) model to recognise drawings sent in by users.
Currently, ACV eats about 75% of the budget for this webapp and the customer is looking for options to reduce costs. After doing a little digging, I've discovered nearly all of the costs of running our ACV instance come from predictions.
I've looked at reducing the frequency of predictions, but since this would impact the functionality of the customer's webap: I am also looking into alternatives.
I've heard "on the grape vine" that it should be possible to export the ACV model and host it as an azure web app in order to reduce costs. I have done some digging, but I haven't found anything substantial on the subject.
What are som techniques/trick that can be used to lower the cost of this model?
